Does the James Webb telescope have a zoom lens?
Does the James Webb telescope have a zoom lens, or does every photo always use max magnification? Or maybe there's no point in using anything less than maximum magnification. If you want a wide area, you just tile the scene.
Right?

@MissUnderstands I have a suggestion to improve the way you ask questions on Stack Exchange. Please don't treat the title as the first line of the question body. The title should summarise and advertise your question, but the question body should be self-contained and not rely on the title in order to make sense. Please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/109403/334566 & https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/145019/334566 & links therein.

Uwe's answer is correct (to my knowledge); however, the various instruments on JWST do have differing fields of view, which is conceptually related to "zoom."

Near-Infrared Camera
"NIRCam has two main fields of view, each of which covers an area of 2.2 × 2.2 arcminutes. Its coronagraphic field of view is smaller."

Near-Infrared Spectrograph
"NIRSpec’s field of view covers a total area of roughly 3 × 3 arcminutes."

Mid-Infrared Instrument
"MIRI’s main field of view is 1.2 × 1.9 arcminutes. The fields of view of its coronagraphs and IFU are smaller."

Near-Infrared Imager and Slitless Spectrograph
"NIRISS covers a field of view roughly 2.2 × 2.2 arcminutes."


Wider fields of view than those do have to be stitched together.

Here's a page on angular diameters (of celestial objects). Interestingly, all the planets are significantly smaller than Webb's viewing areas.

@JollyJoker The key is JWST is diffraction-limited at wavelengths >1.1 µm. Basically, it's as good as it gets for the size of the mirror they could afford.

The James Webb telescope is a mirror telescope. The zooms you may have seen are built with lenses, not with mirrors. Zooming is done by shifting a group of lenses.
The James Webb telescope has three mirrors, a very large primary (18 segments, 6.5 m (21 ft) diameter) and a secondary (74 cm (29 in) diameter) as well as tertiary mirror. There is no group of lenses to be shifted for a variation of the vocal length. This mirror telescope has a fixed focal length of 131.4 m (431 ft).
Source https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope

Nothing precludes zooming by shifting the axial position of mirrors. See US Patent US4812030A. Obscuration is an issue. You can also do it with off-axis reflectors, then it becomes an X-Y motion control nightmare. If you only need discrete zoom, it's much easier.
